# Using a matrix to answer queries in O(1) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, matrix

This is homework, and I already have the answer.  I am just trying to understand what this looks like because I cannot visualize it.

> Suppose that we are given a sequence of n values x1, x2, ..., xn and seek to
>   quickly answer repeated queries of the form: given i and j, find the smallest value
>   in xi, . . . , xj .

and the question is:

> a) Design a data structure that uses O(n^2) space and answers queries in O(1)
>   time.

According to Skienna's wiki page the answer is

> Use an nxn matrix populated with the distance between the nodes at the two indices.

I understand that an n x n matrix would give us n^2 space but I do not understand what this matrix looks like.

Comment: It's simply a lookup table, containing precalculated results for all possible combinations of `i` and `j`.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding what that looks like exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... let's take an example:

For the values: `3 5 4 2`

The matrix will be:

```
3 3 3 2
3 5 4 2
3 4 4 2
2 2 2 2
```

The matrix will always be [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix): we can allow `j < i` as meaning x<sub>j</sub>..x<sub>i</sub>

This is called a *lookup table*. Each value at (i, j) is equal to min(x<sub>i</sub>..x<sub>j</sub>). That means, you *precompute* the values your normal function would return.